# How do I set up miniTT1 and flexTT5 triggers for high speed sync?

Tags: flash, high-speed-sync, pocket-wizard

I am using the Canon 80D camera and a Canon 580ex II speedlight and can't get shutter speeds faster than 1/250s with the flash off the camera. Is anyone familiar with the set-up and use of these triggers?

Comment: How have you got HSS set? Are you trying for HSS? or hypersync?

Comment: would need more information on what settings you are using on your camera, and the triggers to accurately tell you what you need to change, are you shooting in manual mode on the camera and the flashes? auto? program?